# How do I list a folder with a certain name in batch?

Tags: batch-file

Alright, I am making a batch file that reads a group of folders and lists them. An example of a folder looks like this:

Value_1

I am trying to make the batch file read all the folders, then list the ones that have "_1" at the end. So far, I have gotten the script for the batch file to find the folders:

```
:che.fl
if EXIST "*_1" goto success
if NOT EXIST "*_1" goto fail


:success
echo "*_1"
```

I just need help with listing the folders with "_1" at the end. Any ideas?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @aschfipfl said, using `dir /B /A:D *_1` works. However, I did notice the `echo "*_1"` at the `:success` label.

To list all of the folders found, you should just use `dir /B /A:D "*_1"` instead of `echo`.

Comment: Okay,  **dir /A:D *_1** works, any idea how to only show the folders and not the gibberish?

Comment: @HerinAlenta I'll edit my answer shortly to meet your specifications.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: @HerinAlenta I finished editing it, please let me know if you have any issues with the code.

Comment: @Aacini changed my answer to include that. Thanks.